# How to sort a dictionary by key value in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

My test dict is

```
d = {0:'5',28:'5', 23:'5', 21:'5'}
```

and I wrote the code

```
kk = {key:d[key] for key in sorted(d.keys())}
```

which shows the result

```
{0: '5', 28: '5', 21: '5', 23: '5'}
```

but I need

```
{0: '5', 21: '5', 23: '5', 28: '5'}
```

How can I get the **desired result**?

Comment: Which exact version of Python are you using?

Comment: NO . Beacuse I want {0: '5', 21: '5', 23: '5', 28: '5'}

Answer (score 0):

In python, the dictionary data structure is not sequential.
This means there are no differences between {0: 1, 1: 2} and {1: 2, 0: 1}.
Of course, you can sort by keys if you get help from other types than dict, like a list of tuples, but there is another good data type that can be ordered.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Comment: This is only true for old versions of Python.  Current versions have ordered dicts by default.